# Automount encrypted disk with luks on Debian 10 on system start

Tags: linux, debian, encryption, mount, disk-encryption

I try to auto mount disk when system start.
I use crypttab and password have in file in plaintext.

My configuration:

```
sda3_crypt UUID=my_id none luks,discard
wd_01 UUID=my_id /luks-keys/wd1 luks,timeout=180
wd-crypt UUID=my_id /luks-keys/wd1
```

sda3_crypt --> main system

wd_01 --> disk i wanna mount

wd-crypt --> luks partition i wanna mount

And after system start and put main password system boot but don't encrypt wd_01.

When i add mountpoint to fstab it's change. On boot I put my main password , system start boot and after that ask for second password for wd_01 and ignore fact that i put him password to /root/luks-keys/wd1 in crypttab :/

lsblk:

```
NAME              MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                 8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk  
├─sda1              8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2              8:2    0   954M  0 part  /boot
└─sda3              8:3    0 110.4G  0 part  
  └─sda3_crypt    253:0    0 110.4G  0 crypt 
    ├─main-swap   253:1    0   7.5G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─main-system 253:2    0 102.9G  0 lvm   /
sdb                 8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk  
└─sdb-crypt       253:4    0   1.8T  0 crypt /srv/dev-disk-by-label-wd01
sdc                 8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk  
└─seagate_01      253:3    0   1.8T  0 crypt /srv/dev-disk-by-label-seagate01
```

wd_01 is my sdb and wd-crypt is my sdb-crypt

Comment: Hello and welcome to Superuser! Your question is a bit unclear. What is `wd_01` and is it encrypted? Is `wd-crypt` the encrypted mapper of `wd_01`? How have you setup the automatic unlocking via key? Have you updated initramfs? Have you inserted the keys into initramfs? Also add the relevant output of `lsblk` if possible. Please add this information in your question by editing it.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392284/using-a-single-passphrase-to-unlock-multiple-encrypted-disks-at-boot/392286#392286. I used the 2nd solution on the accepted answer. And it worked for me (Ubuntu 19.10).

Comment: @Fanatique i update my post

How have you setup the automatic unlocking via key? 
By add ing key to /root/luks-keys/wd1 in crypttab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i find answer:
I need to add sudo cryptsetup -v luksAddKey

answer: https://blog.tinned-software.net/automount-a-luks-encrypted-volume-on-system-start/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

First a security note, you'll need to protect the file that has the LUKS password or key. That probably means using an encrypted partition for your OS root partition. If you don't protect that file, the encryption doesn't help you much.

Below, substitute `/dev/device-and-part` with your partition (I.E. `sda3`).

Consider backing up your data or any of the files modified in the instructions. It's possible to lose data or make your system inoperable if you make a mistake.

## Create a new LUKS key

Create a key from random data, ensure only root user has access:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/luks-keys/
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/etc/luks-keys/name-of-key bs=512 count=8 iflag=fullblock
sudo chown root.root /etc/luks-keys/name-of-key
sudo chmod 400 /etc/luks-keys/name-of-key
```

Now associate the key with the partition, you'll need to type the existing password at the prompt:

```
sudo cryptsetup -v luksAddKey /dev/device-and-part /etc/luks-keys/name-of-key
```

Verify that that worked, test the key file:

```
sudo cryptsetup open -v --test-passphrase /dev/device-and-part --key-file /etc/luks-keys/name-of-key
```

You can now unlock the encrypted partition with either the password of the key file.

## Unlock and mount

Figure out the UUID for your partition. This unique ID is used to identify the partition at boot time.

```
sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/device-and-part | grep "UUID"
```

Use that value where I write UUID_HERE. Pick a name for your mounted volume, such as `sda3_crypt` for `sda3`. I'll use `name_crypt` in the instructions.

```
echo "name_crypt UUID=UUID_HERE /etc/luks-keys/name-of-key luks" | sudo tee -a /etc/crypttab
```

Check your config using:

```
sudo cryptdisks_start  name_crypt
```

Add to fstab to automount:

```
echo "/dev/mapper/name_crypt /media/path/to/mount ext4 defaults 0 2" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

## Notes

It's worth understanding each of these commands so you can debug any issues you find. `man dd` `man cryptsetup` `man fstab` can help you here. I ran these instructions on Debian 11, the same or a similar approach should work on older/newer Debian releases, Ubuntu, or similar OSes.

Comment: Brilliant answer. This should be marked as the accepted answer @LukaszK .